# Dart 2.0 type annotations

Tags: dart

I'm updating one of my packages to use the latest linter rules, given this :-

```
Map<dynamic,dynamic>obj = Map<dynamic,dynamic>();
P p = P();
String nodename ="name";
obj[nodeName] = [obj[nodeName], p];
```

At the opening bracket of the list on the rhs of the equals I'm getting :-

Specify Type Annotations

Question is why, what does it want me to do here?

Answer (score 2):

This is a List literal `[obj[nodeName], p];` without a generic type.

> latest linter rules

is not very specific, but there are rules that require the types to be specified

```
obj[nodeName] = <dynamic>[obj[nodeName], p];
```

Comment: Ah yes, the first dynamic is OK, it gets rid of the warning, the second one red lines everywhere so we have  obj[nodeName] = <dynamic>[obj[nodeName], p], thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the 2nd is not a list literal, it's a map index access. Didn't look properly